# VBA to Populate one cell in Web Page using Excel List

Tags: excel, vba

I've done lots of testing and tried lots of suggestions but cannot seem to get any to work. I think this is partly due to the way the Web part of the process is set up. With this part of the VBA, I tried naming the input element by declaring the input name but it just doesn't work. The webiste is a company site which is set up in a weird way so hence my struggle.

The code I need uses an excel document with 2 columns - Col A has a list of hyperlinks to each person profile in the web based system, Col B has a person code against each hyperlink.

I therefore need a code which:
1. Clicks the first hyperlink in the Excel Sheet column A & opens in IE in a new page
2. Wait for page to load
3. In Excel Sheet column B, copy first code in list
3. In opened IE page, tab a certain number of times until the correct field is reached (as selecting the input field doesn't work)
4. Paste copied code into field
5. Sendkeys Enter which saves the data to the field
6. Wait for page to load
7. Close the IE page
8. Loop to click next hyperlink in list and repeat process until list ends

If anyone can please help, I would really appreciate it! I'm a VBA novice so any advise, coding would be fantastic.

Many Thanks in advance!
Mike

Here's what i've tried so far (which doesn't work)

```
Sub submitFeedback3()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set links = Sheets("Links List")
Set linkList = links.Range("A1", links.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Set ID = Sheets("Links List")
Set IDList = ID.Range("B1", ID.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
StartTime = Now
    For Each URL In linkList    'open each link
        Shell (browserPath & " " & URL.Value)
    For Each Cel In IDList
        SendKeys "^c"      '= copy
        Set IE = Nothing

Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True


    SendKeys "^v"
    SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    Next Cel
    Next URL


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Updated code:

```
Option Explicit
Const browserPath As String = "C:\Program Files\Internet 
Explorer\iExplore.exe"

Dim IE As Object
Dim LatestDate, StartTime
Dim links As Worksheet, linkList As Range, ID As Worksheet, IDList As Range, 
URL 
As Range, Cel As Range

Sub submitFeedback3()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set links = Sheets("Links List")
Set linkList = links.Range("A1", links.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Set ID = Sheets("Links List")
Set IDList = ID.Range("B1", ID.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))



 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  StartTime = Now
    For Each URL In linkList    'open each link

        Shell (browserPath & " " & URL.Value)
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
     Wend
    For Each Cel In IDList

        SendKeys "^c"      '= copy
    With IE

    .getElementById ("employee.dealerPortalUserId")


    SendKeys "^v"
    SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    End With


    Next Cel
    Next URL


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: With no html shown this is impossible to answer accurately. Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to share HTML to help us to help you. Also, include your coding attempts at the above.

Comment: Have you solved any of the your 1-8 steps? There are copious examples online of how to load up IE with a URL and wait using VBA. From there, it just sounds like Sendkeys (although I think interacting with the DOM would be a better route) as sendkeys should always be a last resort. At any rate, like @qharr says, there is no way we can help here since we have no idea what your web page looks like and the rest is just googling.

Comment: Thanks both - I've added the code above which doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you open a single IE instance using Microsoft Internet Controls and navigate to different URLs rather than creating and destroying in the way you are.

Comment: Hi QHarr, If you'd like to show me this in code, i'd appreciate it, kinda the reason i'm asking!

Comment: Above is my current code - I'm getting a 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error at 'While IE.Busy' if anyone can help?

Comment: [here is link to the example that might help you  do what QHarr suggested ](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)

Comment: Looks really useful, will take a look - Many Thanks Tim!

Comment: if you like you might be able to do this with selenium and vba  have look here https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/